# ASP.NET Security (Multi-user, single computer)

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET Web Form Single Page Application.

It uses Form Security and System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider

The authentication is configured like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFRM" protection="All" timeout="120" loginUrl="~/Authdentication.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

This application is a Point Of Sale. As of now, all employees in the store use the same username/password to login.

Now, we need to add more security into the application.

The ideal situation would be that.

In the morning, cashier #1 and cashier #2 log in using their username and password.

After some time of inactivity, the app locks.

Then, cashier #1 or #2 enters his PIN (5 digit code) different from its password to unlock the app (and auto"magicly") reauthenticate..

Any suggestion, experience with this scenario?

Question:

How can I have multiple user use the same application on the same computer in the same browser window without having to logoff/loggin each time. Behind the scene could occur the logoff / login process but I want the process to be quick and easy for the user.

Comment: Could you please restate your question, so it becomes more specific? Broad suggestions and opinions is not really focus of this site. You described a scenario, what is a specific solvable problem that you have troubles with?

Comment: @zespri, I edited the question. Let me know if this is not clear enough (see end of the Question)

Answer (score 0):

If the idea of using password to login while pin to unlock is to maintain session even when account is locked due to in activity then perhaps you should use different values for forms and session timeouts. For example

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXFRM" protection="All" timeout="15" loginUrl="~/Authdentication.aspx" />
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60"/>
```

This should force you authenticate every 15 minutes you stay inactive but session won't be lost for an hour.